# dispatchTouchEvent and onTouchEvent in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Helle there,

I've been working with the `CoordinateLayout` inside i have `nestedScrollview` layout and it's childs.

It's similar to whats'app profile view. I have tried to mimic this ontouch and dispatchtouch event for more than two days without success.

I read lot about dispatchTouch event `onTouchEvent`, `setOntouchListener`. and it's related video's.

I read about Managing `ViewGroup` reference in android reference, but still it's confuses me. How to handle those touch events.In nestedScrollView i have child `linearlayout` and this layout contains lot of child views like button and edittext.

When i touch `nestedScrollview` (ActionDown) triggered and subsequently (ActionUp) started to scroll, but when i touch any of it's child's view it should wait for the movement of my finger and then start to call `nestedScrollview` if its a (ActionMove).

I've dealing this inside of `AppCompatActivity`.

How do i achieve this? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid enough to play with what i don't understand.

I was able to mimic like whatsapp profile,

```
  @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    nestedScrollview.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
```

call actionMove on child view to consume the event. Voila this did that trick. How ever the Scroll was not smooth compared to the mimic :0

Call this child.setOnTouchListener

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (zeroY < mTouchSlop) {
                        mIsScrolling = true;
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "general" + Float.toString(zeroY) + "  " + Float.toString(plusY));
                    }
                    return true;
```